# Arm ldr diffrent between # and =

Tags: binary-analysis, arm

In ARM assembly, what is the difference between

`ldr r4, =0x44454433`

and

`ldr r4, #0x44454433` ?

Answer (score 4):

the first one **ldr r4, =0x44454433** is a valid pseudo instuction

the second one is invalid

btw the syntax is not for a real instruction but an alias a pseudo instruction

the assembler creates proper instruction with respect to immediate values

most of these questions can be answered by assembling a single instruction and 
disassembling it
you can use armasm from msvc 
or you can use keystone with python or
use the innumerable online assembler disassembler sites

```
import sys
from keystone import *
instruction = raw_input("Enter your arm instruction :  ")
print instruction

ks = Ks(KS_ARCH_ARM,KS_MODE_ARM|KS_MODE_THUMB)
blah = ks.asm(instruction)
for i in blah[0]:
    print "%02x " % i, 
print "\n"
```

executed the script to get

```
:\>python asmarm.py
Enter your arm instruction :  ldr r4,=0x44455533
ldr r4,=0x44455533
00  4c  00  bf  33  55  45  44
```

on the other hand if you try assembling the second instruction it will raise an error unexpected token

```
:\>python asmarm.py
Enter your arm instruction :  ldr r4,=#0x44554533
ldr r4,=#0x44554533
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asmarm.py", line 7, in <module>
    blah = ks.asm(instruction)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\keystone\keystone.py", line 198, in asm
    raise KsError(errno, stat_count.value)
keystone.keystone.KsError: Unknown token in expression (KS_ERR_ASM_EXPR_TOKEN)
```

or you can use capstone to disassemble a hex byte sequence

as below

```
import sys
from capstone import *
import binascii
inp = binascii.unhexlify( ''.join(sys.argv[1].split()))
cs = Cs(CS_ARCH_ARM , CS_MODE_THUMB)
cs.Detail = True
dis = cs.disasm( inp,  int(sys.argv[2],16))
for i in dis:
    print("0x%x:\t" % i.address),
    print(binascii.hexlify(i.bytes)),
    print("\t%s\t%s" %(i.mnemonic, i.op_str))
```

executing the script

```
:\>discap.py "00  4c  00  bf  33  55  45  44" 0x440000
0x440000:       004c    ldr     r4, [pc, #0]
0x440002:       00bf    nop
0x440004:       3355    strb    r3, [r6, r4]
0x440006:       4544    add     r5, r8
```

if you use msvc route you need to open a vsdev cmdprompt with a proper architecxture and simple use armasm with an input file  as below

set correct arch and host

```
C:\>cat bld.bat
pushd ..    
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd.bat" -arch=arm -host_arch=x86
```

src file contents

```
C:\>cat myasm.asm
    AREA .text, CODE, ARM
test PROC
    ldr r4,=0x44455533
    ENDP    
    END
```

execute and open a msvc arm devprompt

```
C:\>bld.bat

C:\>pushd ..

C:\>call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd.bat" -arch=arm -host_arch=x86
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.6.1
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
C:\>popd
```

assemble the input file

```
C:\>armasm myasm.asm
Microsoft (R) ARM Macro Assembler Version 14.13.26128.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

disassemble the obj file

```
C:\>dumpbin /disasm myasm.obj
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.13.26128.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file myasm.obj

File Type: COFF OBJECT

test:
  00000000: 4C00      ldr         r4,00000004
  00000002: 0000      movs        r0,r0
  00000004: 5533      strb        r3,[r6,r4]
  00000006: 4445      add         r5,r5,r8

  Summary

          60 .debug$S
           8 .text

C:\>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for showing *capstone* and *keystone*.

Comment: What pip [package](https://github.com/keystone-engine/keystone) is *keystone*?

Answer (score 3):

Although this is be a simple [LMGTFY](http://lmgtfy.com) question, I'm going to answer since it took me some time to find it.

Assuming it's 32bit ARM all the opcodes are 4 bytes long so this poses a question how one can include a 32bit value in the opcode if opcode with such big data would not fit in 4 bytes.

```
ldr r4, =0x44454433
```

is a pseudo-instruction.

> The LDR Rd,=const pseudo-instruction generates the most efficient single instruction to load any 32-bit number. - page [6-111](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.100069_0610_00_en/armasm_user_guide_100069_0610_00_en.pdf)

The other const `#0x44454433` is just a const value, but with this form (having 32 bit value in it and just the value) seems invalid (not an expert on ARM).

Comment: Correct. It just a convenient *shorthand* notation for "load a large constant from a nearby address". It is not an instruction in itself; a disassembler may choose to show it that way, but the actual code is something different.

Comment: If you're curious about what immediate values can be represented in the instruction directly, I thought this was a nice resource: https://alisdair.mcdiarmid.org/arm-immediate-value-encoding/