# arm branch calculator

Tags: exception

When I use this opcode `09E0` that mean `B  #0x12` that mean go to pc+0x12 .(relative address)

How can I jump with `B` to pc-0x12  (relative address)?

Comment: This is a very basic question, it's a good idea to read up on Thumb instruction encoding - and take care of the byte order, the instruction itself is a 16-bit instruction 0xE009 (see http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0210c/CACBCAAE.html). Branch offsets are 2's complement numbers, so you simply replace the least significant 11 bits of the 16-bit word with the offset shifted one bit to the right (since Thumb instructions only start on even addresses).

Answer (score 0):

**B #0x12** will normally yield **07 e0**  in arm thumb mode 
B #0x16 would yoeld 09 e0

you f7 e7 will translate to B #-14

```
Enter your arm instruction :  b #-14
b #-14
f7  e7
```

i just wrote an answer on how to use either keystone in python or msvc to assemble single instruction and disassemble it

so please refe that answer **[HOW TO ASSSEMBLE SINGLE INSTRUCTIONS AND DISASSEMBLE IN ARM](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17786/arm-ldr-diffrent-between-and)**